# How can i align an image next to a div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an image with a div that contains two rows of text like this:

[image]

Here is my current

```
<div class="first-div">
  <img class="img" src="/image-icon.png" />

  <div class="second-div">
    <p class="m-0">hello world</p>
    <p class="m-0">hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

my current css:

```
.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: center;

}

.first-div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-top: bottom;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

But i cant seem to align them without having to add a bottom margin to the picture which i assume is the wrong way of going about this.

i created a js fiddle so you guys can take a look https://jsfiddle.net/sav1bpk0/25/

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a straight up duplicate as the OP has mostly the correct way to do it but just need a little tweaking

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sav1bpk0/49/ check this out

Comment: @Huangism tweaking or not, the purpose is the same "vertical align" ... the below answer make it a clear duplicate because it's the one you will find in the 3 links I shared and more links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the height on the second box, also `vertical-align` should be set to middle like you did to the img, not center

```
.second-div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

When you set a height to the second box, while the box is aligned to the image since they have the same height, but the content inside of the box is not vertically aligned.

Comment: Thanks this worked, i will accept the answer when it lets me.